# Stackoverflow WYSIWYG Pagedown.js Editor restricting live preview to on click rather than on keyup

Tags: javascript, markdown, wysiwyg, pagedown

This very textbox I'm typing in on Stackoverflow uses [Pagedown.js](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) markdown to HTML conversion.

I'd like to use the Pagedown.js editor but only show the live preview HTML `onclick` rather than `onkeyup`. My reasoning is that for mobile devices the keyup-based parsing seems too taxing (SO itself doesn't use it) and it would provide just as nice a user experience to click a button to reveal the formatted text.

Is there any way to separate out `editor.run()` such that the button bar formatting (e.g., bracketing text with asterisks) and the live preview formatting can be uncoupled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the refresh by calling `editor.refreshPreview()` after calling `editor.run()`. However, the `onkeyup` event doesn't  seem to be configurable. You can disable it by changing `var startType = "delayed"` to `"manual"` in `Markdown.Editor.js`.

Comment: -@benweet Thanks for the tips! So just so I'm clear, hard coding `startType` to `manual` in editor.js prevents  `makePreviewHtml()` from happening in which case I can then call `editor.refreshPreview()` on user `click`? I kinda don't see the point of having `editor.refreshPreview()` unless `startType` is option during `editor` initialization.

Comment: -@benweet, just implemented this, your suggestions work perfectly! Thanks!